# RTP media sample rate

Tags: c++, network-protocols, rtp, pcap, sdp

I'm writing a c++ code to parse RTP streams and calculate the jitter for the stream. However, I need the media sample rate (which is set in the SDP invitation). My question is, is there any other simpler way to get this info other than having to parse the SDP packet and extract this info from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that each rtp header has a payload type and the mapping between every static type and their corresponding sample rate can be looked up here

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3551#page-32

Sample rates for dynamic payload types however should be extracted from the SDP invitation.